# Different where condition for each column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to write query like this in SQL Server, without using select two times and then join?

```
select trans_date, datepart(HOUR,trans_time) as hour,
(datepart(MINUTE,trans_time)/30)*30 as minute,
case 
when paper_number = 11111/*paperA*/
then sum(t1.price*t1.amount)/SUM(t1.amount)*100 
end as avgA,
case 
when paper_number = 22222/*PaperB*/
then sum(t1.price*t1.amount)/SUM(t1.amount)*100 
end as avgB
from dbo.transactions t1
where trans_date = '2006-01-01' and (paper_number = 11111 or paper_number = 22222)
group by trans_date, datepart(HOUR,trans_time), datepart(MINUTE,trans_time)/30 
order by hour, minute
```

SQL Server asks me to add paper_number to group by, and returns nulls when I do so

```
trans_date  hour    minute  avgA                avgB
2006-01-01  9       30      1802.57199725463    NULL
2006-01-01  9       30      NULL                169125.886524823
2006-01-01  10      0       1804.04742534103    NULL
2006-01-01  10      0       NULL                169077.777777778
2006-01-01  10      30      1806.18773535637    NULL
2006-01-01  10      30      NULL                170274.550381867
2006-01-01  11      0       1804.43466045433    NULL
2006-01-01  11      0       NULL                170743.4
2006-01-01  11      30      1807.04532012137    NULL
2006-01-01  11      30      NULL                171307.00280112
```

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: trans_date hour minute avgA avgB
1/1/01 9 30 14 15
Hope that helps...

Comment: can you add it along with your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
with cte as
(select trans_date, 
        datepart(HOUR,trans_time) as hour, 
        (datepart(MINUTE,trans_time)/30)*30 as minute,
        sum(case when paper_number = 11111/*paperA*/ 
                 then t1.price*t1.amount else 0 end) as wtdSumA,
        sum(case when paper_number = 11111/*paperA*/ 
                 then t1.amount else 0 end) as amtSumA,
        sum(case when paper_number = 22222/*PaperB*/ 
                 then t1.price*t1.amount else 0 end) as wtdSumB,
        sum(case when paper_number = 22222/*PaperB*/ 
                 then t1.amount else 0 end) as amtSumB
from dbo.transactions t1
where trans_date = '2006-01-01'
group by trans_date, datepart(HOUR,trans_time), datepart(MINUTE,trans_time)/30)
select trans_date, hour, minute,
       case amtSumA when 0 then 0 else 100 * wtdSumA / amtSumA end as avgA,
       case amtSumB when 0 then 0 else 100 * wtdSumB / amtSumB end as avgB
from cte
order by hour, minute
```

(SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62074/4))

You can derive this without the CTE, like so:

```
select trans_date, 
       datepart(HOUR,trans_time) as hour, 
       (datepart(MINUTE,trans_time)/30)*30 as minute,
       case sum(case when paper_number = 11111/*paperA*/ then t1.amount else 0 end)
            when 0 then 0 
            else 100 * sum(case when paper_number = 11111 then t1.price*t1.amount else 0 end)
                 / sum(case when paper_number = 11111 then t1.amount else 0 end) end as avgA,
       case sum(case when paper_number = 22222/*paperA*/ then t1.amount else 0 end)
            when 0 then 0 
            else 100 * sum(case when paper_number = 22222 then t1.price*t1.amount else 0 end)
                 / sum(case when paper_number = 22222 then t1.amount else 0 end) end as avgB
from dbo.transactions t1
where trans_date = '2006-01-01'
group by trans_date, datepart(HOUR,trans_time), datepart(MINUTE,trans_time)/30
order by 1,2,3
```

Comment: Yes the end result is correct, but may be there is a simpler way?(without select from select)

Comment: @MichaelCherevko: You can rewrite the query without the select from select, but I'm not sure I would regard it as simpler - see my updated answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

Use SUM() function on the entire CASE expression

```
select trans_date, datepart(HOUR,trans_time) as hour, (datepart(MINUTE,trans_time)/30)*30 as minute,
       sum(case when paper_number = 11111/*paperA*/ then t1.price*t1.amount end) * 1.00
       / sum(case when paper_number = 11111/*paperA*/ then t1.amount end) * 100 as avgA,
       sum(case when paper_number = 22222/*PaperB*/ then t1.price*t1.amount end) * 1.00
       / sum(case when paper_number = 22222/*paperB*/ then t1.amount end) * 100 as avgB
from dbo.transactions t1
where trans_date = '2006-01-01'
group by trans_date, datepart(HOUR,trans_time), datepart(MINUTE,trans_time)/30 
order by hour, minute
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62074/13)

Comment: Note that `t1.price*t1.amount/t1.amount` is equivalent to just `t1.price` (where `t1.amount` is not 0) - to get the weighted average of the price, you need to divide the sum of the amount-weighted price by the sum of the amount.

Comment: Correct, I get results for both avga and avgb but the calculations are wrong

Comment: @Mark Bannister Thanks for the clarifications! Answer updated. and +1 in your answer;)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` like below:

```
WITH prepared AS (
  SELECT
    trans_date,
    trans_time = DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00', trans_time) / 30 * 30, CAST('00:00' AS time)),
    paper_number,
    total = price * amount,
    amount
  FROM transactions
),
unpivoted AS (
  SELECT
    trans_date,
    trans_time,
    attribute = attribute + CAST(paper_number AS varchar(10)),
    value
  FROM prepared
  UNPIVOT (value FOR attribute IN (total, amount)) u
),
pivoted AS (
  SELECT
    trans_date,
    trans_time,
    avgA = total11111 * 100 / amount11111,
    avgB = total22222 * 100 / amount22222
  FROM unpivoted
  PIVOT (
    SUM(value) FOR attribute IN (total11111, amount11111, total22222, amount22222)
  ) p
)
SELECT *
FROM pivoted
;
```

As an attempt at explaining how the above query works, below is a description of transformations that the original dataset undergoes in the course of the query's execution, using the following example:

```
trans_date  trans_time  paper_number  price  amount
----------  ----------  ------------  -----  ------
2013-04-09  11:12:35    11111         10     15
2013-04-09  11:13:01    22222         24     10
2013-04-09  11:28:44    11111         12     5
2013-04-09  11:36:20    22222         20     11
```

1. The `prepared` CTE produces the following column set:

   ```
   trans_date  trans_time  paper_number  total  amount
   ----------  ----------  ------------  -----  ------
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    11111         150    15
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    22222         240    10
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    11111         60     5
   2013-04-09  11:30:00    22222         220    11
   ```

   where `trans_time` is the original `trans_time` rounded down to the nearest half-hour and `total` is `price` multiplied by `amount`.
2. The `unpivoted` CTE unpivots the `total` and `amount` values to produce `attribute` and `value`:

   ```
   trans_date  trans_time  paper_number  attribute  value
   ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------  -----
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    11111         total      150
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    11111         amount     15
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    22222         total      240
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    22222         amount     10
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    11111         total      60
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    11111         amount     5
   2013-04-09  11:30:00    22222         total      220
   2013-04-09  11:30:00    22222         amount     11
   ```

   Then `paper_number` is combined with `attribute` to form a single column, also called `attribute`:

   ```
   trans_date  trans_time  attribute  value
   ----------  ----------  -----------  -----
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    total11111   150
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    amount11111  15
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    total22222   240
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    amount22222  10
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    total11111   60
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    amount11111  5
   2013-04-09  11:30:00    total22222   220
   2013-04-09  11:30:00    amount22222  11
   ```
3. Finally, the `pivoted` CTE pivots the `value` data back aggregating them along the way with `SUM()` and using the `attribute` values for column names:

   ```
   trans_date  trans_time  total11111  amount11111  total22222  amount22222
   ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------  ----------  -----------
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    210         20           240         10
   2013-04-09  11:30:00    NULL        NULL         220         11
   ```

   The pivoted values are then additionally processed (every `totalNNN` is multiplied by 100 and divided by the corresponding `amountNNN`) to form the final output:

   ```
   trans_date  trans_time  avgA  avgB
   ----------  ----------  ----  ----
   2013-04-09  11:00:00    1050  2400
   2013-04-09  11:30:00    NULL  2000
   ```

There's a couple of issues that may need to be addressed:

1. If `price` and `amount` are different data types, the `total` and `amount` may end up different data types as well. For `UNPIVOT`, it is mandatory that the values being unpivoted are of exactly the same type, and so you'll need to add an explicit conversion of `total` and `amount` to some common type, possibly one which would prevent data/precision loss. That would could be done in the `prepared` CTE like this (assuming the common type to be `decimal(10,2)`):

   ```
   total  = CAST(price * amount AS decimal(10,2)),
   amount = CAST(amount AS decimal(10,2))
   ```
2. If aggregated amounts may ever end up 0, you'll need to account for the division by 0 issue. One way to do that could be to substitute the 0 amount with NULL, which would make the result of the division NULL as well. Applying `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` to that result would allow you to transform it to some default value, 0 for instance. So, change this bit in the `pivoted` CTE:

   ```
   avgA = ISNULL(total11111 * 100 / NULLIF(amount11111, 0), 0),
   avgB = ISNULL(total22222 * 100 / NULLIF(amount22222, 0), 0)
   ```

Comment: Perfect explanation!and thanks for a trick with ISNULL(...NULLIF()) +1;)